# SQL Azure database using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've been trying to work out whether it's possible to manage (i.e. add tables, modify them, create stored procedures) a SQL Azure database using some kind of GUI like SSMS and I keep coming up against different answers.

I found a post from the end of 2009 saying that it would be supported in SSMS but I'm not sure if that includes the Express version? Does anybody know what the most recent update of the express version is and whether it supports it?

I think I'm right in saying that it can't be done in Visual Web Developer 2010 (and I can't afford the full fat VS2010).

I'm prepared to consider alternatives though if anybody knows any full features GUI tools that work with SQL azure and I don't mind paying for a commercial license if it's not too expensive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server **2008 R2**'s Management Studio does support working with SQL Azure databases.

See:

- [Getting Started with SQL Azure Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309175.aspx)

Comment: Does that include the express version? Also, is there a way to design tables in it?

Comment: @jonhobbs: yes, it seems like that would work, too - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/02/10019029.aspx

Comment: For me, SSMS only works to execute scripts. You know if I can do anything to work with design mode?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options
1) You can use SSMS (get the free version by downloading SQL Express v2008 or greater) with advanced services.  This will give you SSMS. You can then connect to SQL Azure using SSMS.  However - there is a limited set of functionality available via this tool.
2) You can use SSDT (stand-alone for free) or from within VS2010 SP1 or greater.  Again, you can connect to SQL Azure, but there are some restrictions on what you can do.

I am using the SQL Express on AWS RDS (free usage tier) myself lately (and connecting via SSMS or SSDT).  I prefer their implementation of SQL Server in the cloud to Microsoft's implementation of SQL Azure.